# Postgres Set Select Value In If

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to set the value of a column in a select statement but only in a certain condition.

Something like the following:

```
SELECT 
IF (MIN(mode) <> MAX(mode))
THEN
    "Start Mode" = 'Multiple' 
ELSE
    "Method" = MIN(mode)
ENDIF
FROM sessions
--Where condition here
```

The statement above produces errors. It is possible to use IF statements in selects like this?

**EDIT**

I want to determine what the start mode was. It can be WEB or CALL. It is possible to have multiple start modes. In that case (`MIN` doesnt equal `MAX`), then I want to set the Start Mode Column to multiple.

I could use "mode" as the column name, this select will be in a larger sql script which will generate a large table that we will export to a .csv. We want the column names to be clear for the people using the csv.

Samples:

```
Userid Mode 
1     WEB
1     CALL
2     WEB
2     WEB

csv
User Id   Start Mode
1         Multiple
2         WEB
```

Comment: This can be done using a `CASE` statement. But I'm totally confused about `"Start Mode" = 'Multiple'`. What is that supposed to do? Please add some sample data and the expected output from that data.

Comment: See edits. I added more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
User_id, 
CASE WHEN (MIN(mode) <> MAX(mode))
THEN
    'Multiple' 
ELSE
    MIN(mode)
END
as "Start Mode"
FROM sessions
--Where condition here
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Consider the chapter [identifiers and key words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) and use *single quotes* (`'`) for values in Postgres.